# Is there a better way to create an array while looping through an object's method?

Tags: php, arrays, object, loops

I'm using

```
foreach ($objs as $obj) {
    $data[] = $obj->getValue;
}
```

to collect values from a method which may return

```
array[4]{
    [0]=>
    string(2) "1234"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "5678"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "9ab"
    [3]=>
    string(10) "cdefg"
    ...
}
```

But I need that data in a multidimensional associative array format like...

```
array[2]{
[0] =>
    array[2]{
        ["alpha"]=>
        string(2) "1234"
        ["beta"]=>
        string(7) "5678"
    }
[1] =>
    array[2]{
        ["alpha"]=>
        string(7) "9ab"
        ["beta"]=>
        string(10) "cdefg"
}
```

I've been able to do this with two independent loops, one that loops the method data into a two dimensional array, and the second that loops through that array and manually changes the index values to associative values.

```
    $key_labels = array('alpha','beta');
    $row_num = $col_num = 0;
    $rows = array(
                array(),
                array()
            );

    /* Parse the query into a two-dimensional array */
    foreach ($objs as $obj) {
        $rows[$row_num][$col_num++] = $obj->nodeValue;

        if ($col_num == count($key_labels)) {   
            $col_num = 0;
            $row_num++;
        }
    }

    /* Change the array second dimension index values to associative values */
    foreach ($rows as $rows_idx => $row) {
        unset($rows[$rows_idx]);
        foreach ($row as $row_idx => $row_val) {
            $rows[$rows_idx][$key_labels[$row_idx]] = $row_val;
        }
    }

    var_dump($rows);
```

My question is... is there a way to accomplish this more directly than using two verbose (and seemingly clunky) loops?  Or is this really the best way?

Note: It is expected that the object will always return a number of rows equal to some even factor of the `$key_labels` count.

Comment: Are you arbitrarily determining "alpha" and "beta" by grouping the objects in 2? Is "alpha"/"beta" stored somewhere in the object?

Comment: @Ayman Unfortunately yes, no other indicator is stored in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untested, and needs php 5.3. But you can just replace the array_map and anonymous function with another foreach if you dont have 5.3

```
$vals = array();
foreach ($objs as $obj) {
    $vals[] = $obj->nodeValue;
}

$key_labels = array('alpha','beta');

$result = array_map(array_chunk($vals, count($key_labels)), function($chunkOfVals) use ($key_labels) {
    return array_combine($key_labels, $chunkOfVals);
});
```

edit - heres the non 5.3 way. To be honest, I like this way better after writing it out. Much more clear.

```
$result = array();
foreach (array_chunk($vals, count($key_labels)) as $chunkOfVals) {
    $result[] = array_combine($key_labels, $chunkOfVals);
}
```

Comment: Beautiful!  I'm going with the second method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($objs as $j => $obj) {
  $data[$j % 2 == 0 ? ++$i : $i][$j % 2 == 0 ? 'alpha' : 'beta'] = $obj->getValue;
}

var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can use a specific obj value for array key :

```
foreach( $objs as $obj) {
     $array[$obj->name] = $obj->getValues();
}
```

Or create a method that get the array pass by ref.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing my hat in the ring:

```
$myArray = array();
$tempArray = array();

$counter = 0;
foreach($objs as $obj) {

    $tempArray[$key_labels[$counter % 2]] = $obj->getValue;

    if($counter % 2 == 0) {
        $myArray[] = $tempArray;
        $tempArray = array();
    }

    $counter++;
}
```

Full demo here: http://codepad.org/dCX9KEcB

Result looks like:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["alpha"]=>
    int(12345)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["beta"]=>
    int(78945)
    ["alpha"]=>
    int(43579)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["beta"]=>
    int(29853)
    ["alpha"]=>
    int(63542)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["beta"]=>
    int(75675)
    ["alpha"]=>
    int(12233)
  }
```